# How to filter Docker images by platform?

Tags: docker

I am using LCOW and WCOW at the same time on a Windows 10 machine. There are lots of images in both platforms. I want to see all the images of a specific platform.

Is there a way to make `docker images` show only the images that are for e.g. Linux?

Comment: Are you able to distinct the images using `--filter` flag?

Comment: I have looked [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#list-image-digests) for filter types. However, I couldn't find a related filter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find the docker image platforms using the command

```
docker image inspect <image id>
```

Look for the "Os" attribute value

To list all the images and their respective OSs

```
for i in `docker images --format {{.ID}}`; do echo $i `docker image inspect $i |grep Os`; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Here is the PowerShell version I wrote: `docker images --format "{{.ID}}" | ForEach-Object { $os = docker image inspect $_ | Select-String -Pattern '"Os":*'; Write-Host $_ -NoNewLine; Write-Host $os }`

Comment: If you happened to want to filter based on CPU architecture instead, you want `Architecture` in place of `Os`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72421393/list-docker-images-for-arm-from-the-cli   OS and PLATFORM are two different things