# How can I resolve the OS platform of a docker image?

Tags: docker

Is there a way to determine the operating system version of a docker image programmatically without pulling the image or inspecting the docker file?

When I look at popular images on docker hub (e.g. `openjdk`), it seems that the convention is to encode the operating system into the tag name (e.g. `windowsservercore-1803`). The problem with this approach is that not all images might follow this convention.

It seems that docker actually knows the platform, because when I pull an `nginx` image on Windows it complains that the platform is not supported by the image.

Does docker offer an API driven mechanism to resolve the operating system platform for a given image name and tag?

I found [How to filter Docker images by platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870431/how-to-filter-docker-images-by-platform) but that requires that the image has already been pulled. I am looking for a solution that allows me to query a registry with `image:tag` and retrieve the `os/arch` without pulling the image.

I also found https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/manifest/ but that is still experimental and it also looks like it needs the manifest file to be present on the local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Approach 1 - Docker engine API

You can get the image information with the [docker engin API: Get image information from the registry](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/#operation/DistributionInspect)

For example, you need to get the platform information for image `openjdk` with tag `10.0.1-jdk-windowsservercore-1709`, you can call the docker engine API as below:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock  "http://v1.39/distribution/openjdk:10.0.1-jdk-windowsservercore-1709/json"
```

PS: v1.39 is my docker version, you should replace it according to your docker environment.

Response:

```
{
    "Descriptor":{
        "mediaType":"application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
        "digest":"sha256:8394bc010c538ffc5f56386466a728d205edd70317bd320aa44e50c8533a229a",
        "size":480
    },
    "Platforms":[
        {
            "architecture":"amd64",
            "os":"windows",
            "os.version":"10.0.16299.547"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `Platforms` field should be what you need:

> An array containing all platforms supported by the image

There is a [doc](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/examples/) describing how to call the docker engine API.

## Approach 2 - Docker Registry API

To call docker registry API, you simply need a http client, eg. `curl`, no docker client is needed.

### 1. Get an authorization token.

Pls refer [Token Authentication Specification](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/token/) for more detail.

For example, you need to make query to image `library/openjdk`

```
curl --url "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:library/openjdk:pull"
```

**`scope`** field indicate which `image` you need to query in the subsequence API invocation.

Response:

```
{"token": "eyJhb......"}
```

Save the `token` from the response above.

### 2. Get image manifest

Reference:

2.1. [Docker Registry HTTP API V2#manifest](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#manifest)
2.2. [Image mainfest](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/)

For example, you need to get the manifest of image `openjdk`, with tag `10.0.1-jdk-windowsservercore-1709`, then you can make a request like this:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJh..." --url "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/library/openjdk/manifests/10.0.1-jdk-windowsservercore-1709"
```

**Note**: Replace the `Authorization` header field with the token you get from step 1. Make sure to insert a prefix before the token with `Bearer`

Response:

```
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
  "manifests": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "size": 2825,
      "digest": "sha256:c8a1d8756ae34cdf361da263ed3f7ef98b7dc3718d5e445e8e6bd277989a4bde",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "amd64",
        "os": "windows",
        "os.version": "10.0.16299.547"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The `manifests[i].platform.os` field should be what you need.

Comment: This only seems to work, when I query the local docker engine. Is there a way to make this work when I query directly against Docker hub or Artifactory?

Comment: I have updated the answer with another approach using pure http API, hope it would help...

Comment: One more thing, this works fine for public images such as openjdk, but when I try it with my own image on Artifactory, then I get `MANIFEST_UNKNOWN`, do I need to explicitly add a manifest for my image?

Comment: Do you mean the `JFrog Artifactory`?

Comment: Yes exactly. We have setup a virtual repository, that links a private development repository with the public docker hub. When I query a public image that is on the docker hub, then I get the proper manifest information back, but when I query an image on the private registry that I uploaded my self, then I get the unknown manifest error.

Comment: Umm.. I didn't use the jfrog product before, but as the doc mentions: the artifactory registry API is compatible with the docker registry API, https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry.. did u use the correct API domain? I think you can't use the public docker registry to query the private repo...