# List Docker images for ARM from the CLI

Tags: docker, macos

I own a Mac M1 and I run Docker on it.
On OSX, Docker can run native ARM images but also emulate x86/amd64 to run images that were not built for ARM.

My question is simple: From the command line, I am trying to find an extension of the command 'docker image ls' which displays the image **platform**.

$ docker image ls

REPOSITORY   TAG     **PLATFORM**  IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE
.............................arm64
.............................x86

I already saw this answer: [How to filter Docker images by platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870431/how-to-filter-docker-images-by-platform) but it does NOT answer the question. OS and PLATFORM are two different things.

Thank you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Is this what you looking for?

```bash
docker image inspect --format "{{.ID}} {{.RepoTags}} {{.Architecture}}" $(docker image ls -q)
```

output:

```
sha256:fb495265b81ffaa0d3bf8887231b954a1139b2e3d611c3ac3ddeaff72313909c [postgres:10.11-alpine] amd64
```

Explanation:

- `$(docker image ls -q)` → pass all image IDs as parameters to inspect command
- `docker image inspect` print detailed info about image

  - `--format "{{.ID}} {{.RepoTags}} {{.Architecture}}"` → [print only necessary data](https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/) instead of full JSON

Also it is possible to add pipe with `grep`, like `{inspect command} | egrep 'amd64$'` to print only `amd64` architecture for example

Comment: This is a good answer, but by now I do wish for a `docker image ls -l` option out of the box that would include a platform column :-)

Answer (score 6):

Try to combine `docker image` with `jq` :

```
docker image inspect $(docker images -q) | jq -r '.[] | select(.Architecture=="arm64").RepoTags[]'
```